# PHP Shorthand ifelse understanding

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to make some sense out of the following shorthand

```
 $state = $account->getCity() ? $account->getCity()->getStates() : null;
```

Is my understanding right?

if `$account->getCity()` exist assign the value of `$account->getCity()->getStates()` to the `$state` variable else assign is `null`

Reason I am asking this is because I m getting the error

> Error: Call to a member function getCity() on a non-object

If the code `$state = $account->getCity() ? $account->getCity()->getStates() : null;` does not check to see if `$account->getCity()` is null then how do I make it so it checks it.

The output I am trying to achieve is

if `$account->getCity()` is not null assign the value of `$account->getCity()->getStates()` to the `$state` else just make it null

Hopefully I am not sounding too confusing :)

Comment: What you're asking about is a *ternary operator*. The error isn't that your ternary operator is wrong, but the fact that you're trying to use a mathod that's designed to be used on objects on something that isn't an object. You'll need to check where you define `$account` and make sure it's an object that you can use the method `getCity()` on

Comment: @Qirel thanks, I can confirm that `$account` is an object and sometimes the `getCity()` is null and sometimes its not and when its `null` thats when the error is thrown and that's what I am trying to handle. I want `$state` to be null when `$account->getCity()` is `null`

Comment: Try `!empty($account->getCity()) ? $account->getCity()->getStates() : null;` instead.

Comment: @Qirel ya i tried it but it does not work.

Comment: Still getting "Call to a member function getCity() on a non-object"? Then you can add another check, making *sure* it's an object. `!empty($account->getCity()) && is_object($account) ? $account->getCity()->getStates() : null`

Comment: @Qirel thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using what is known as "ternary operator" shorthand. However, you're using the `$account->getCity()` `method` to try and check if `$account->getCity()` exists, resulting in the problem.

A better practice would be to use `isset($account->getCity())` or `(!empty($account->getCity()))` to evaluate if it exists. It is worth noting that `isset()` will check if it exists, where as `empty()` will check if it exists AND is filled with a value. As comments mention, you may also need to check that the `object` is actually an `object`, which can be done with `is_object($object)`, such as using `(is_object($account) && !empty($account->getCity())`.

A common issue seen is that a variable or object may be assigned, but the contents are empty, similar to using `$variable = '';`. Checking using `empty()` may save you the heartache of coming across this problem down the road.

An additional side note is that while ternary operators are fantastic, they are best used when both a `true` and `false` condition are supplied. If you insist, try to at least use `null` in place of `''` in the operation.